# Using brackets within a cookie name – Why does PHP turn it into an array?

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm trying to use brackets within the name of a cookie.

It is supposed to look like this(this is how the browser wants it!):

```
Name: name[123456].newName
Content: 20
```

Here is my example:

```
$cookie = "name[123456].newName=20"
```

But when I analyze what the browser sees, I get this:

```
cookie['name'] = Array
```

And I want:

```
cookie['name[123456].newName'] = 20
```

My question is: How should I write the cookies name in a way that the browser understands?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Arggh. This is bound to cause problems. Why do you need this?

Comment: That sure is horrible, but they are all allowed chars for cookies, can you give a more complete example of how you add the cookie for curl?

Comment: When I check the cookie in chrome it looks like this:

name[123456].newName

And when I check the cookie in a webformanalyzer the cookie is like I showed in the previous example.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, all you have to do is this:

```
<?php

setcookie('name[123456].newName', 20);

?>
```

This generates the following header:

```
Set-Cookie: name[123456].newName=20
```

... and browsers (well, at least Firefox) seem to handle it just fine.

The issue starts when you want to read the value back. PHP has an otherwise nice feature: whenever it finds an input parameter (get, post, cookie...) with square brackets on its name, it'll build an array from it. So `print_r($_COOKIE)` displays this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [123456] => 20
        )

)
```

I'm not aware of any way to disable this feature so you probably need to use string functions and parse the contents of the raw cookie, which can be found at `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']`:

```
name[123456].newName=20
```

Comment: +1. I don't think this feature is nice though; actually I think it's a serious PHP design flaw. You can often trip scripts up by sending them an array `a[]` where they are expecting a single value `a` (leaving them with the wrong datatype!), and they can't parse multiple inputs with the same name without `[]`. It would have been much better to have separate superglobals for single-value inputs and multiple-value inputs.

Comment: Yes, this is how the browser gets the cookies. And it can read it?

Comment: @Christopher, can you be more precise? What don't you understand exactly?

Comment: The problem is that the receiving end doesn't read the cookies.

Comment: What receiving end are you talking about? Have you printed the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']` on screen?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, when I print out $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKE'] I get the correct cookies.

The problem is still that the webpage(the receiving end) is not understanding the values I'm sending. It's making me mad!

Example:
`"name[834788].newName=20; name[865063].newName=20;"`

Comment: Well, the value at `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKE']` contains what the other site sent back. And I'm afraid that "does not understand" is not a better description that "does not work". Are you coding the remote site as well?